# Использование библиотеки сURL.

Tags: curl, c++

Решил написать парсер страниц на плюсах и возникла проблема с подключением библиотеки.
Скачал все нужные файлы *.h закинул в папку инклуд компилятора. lib файли в паку lib. Dll'ли в  папку System32. Набросал код, а компилятор к многим строкам кода выдает такие ошибки: "error C3861: 'curl_ease_init': identifier not found" и т.д.

**Что я мог упустить при добавлении библиотеки? Заранее благодарен!**

Comment: >Решил написать парсер страниц на плюсах

Уже весело.

Answer (score 2):

раз в названии ошибки есть `error C3861`, это значит, что используется майкрософтовский компилятор.

> > Скачал все нужные файлы *.h закинул в папку инклуд компилятора.

так не нужно делать.

> > lib файли в паку lib.

Тем более.

> > Dll'ли в папку System32.

Иногда это нужно, но по большей части  можно просто оставить рядом с бинарником и не засорять папку винды. Там и так помойка.

Как это нужно сделать.

- распаковываем архив с библиотекой. Можно в какое-то свое место, можно рядом, в каталог с проектом. Скачать [здесь](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), в самом низу, в разделе "Win32 - MSVC".
- В каталоге находим  файл `libcurl.lib`. Запоминаем  путь. lib файлы находятся в двух папках - release debug - это для двух разных конфигураций. Вы для начала наверное будете только Debug собирать. Поэтому правильный каталог - `libcurl.lib`
- используя меню `Solution->properties->Link(ing)` добавляем `libcurl.lib` к проекту.
- `.h` файлы наиболее просто скопировать к себе в проект - в папке с исходниками создайте каталог `curl` и скопируйте туда содержимое папки `include/curl`. В будущем научитесь разбираться, какие файлы нужны, какие нет.
- пытаемся скомпилировать. Должно получится, но не будет запускаться. Для этого копируем dll файл с каталога `lib/Debug` рядом к бинарнику.